# Can't find where *exactly* my app submission is wrong (rejected because of translation issues with open graph stories)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have submitted a custom open graph story, but it's being rejected with this message:

Open Graph
Donate (Action Type)
Submissions, actions, objects and usage instructions must be submitted in English. You can translate actions and objects in the Localize tab of the App Dashboard.

If i click on the localize tab, I find that all strings are translated. Everything else in the app was previously accepted, so there should be no issues elsewhere (and the "Open Graph" tab is the only one that shows a warning icon).

Where can I find *exactly* which is the problem with my submission?

Comment: Are you sure nothing changed? You said everything else was previously accepted. Remove anything that wasn't there when you submitted it before. If it fails, something changed that you forgot about. If it works, you know something new is breaking it. Start re-adding pieces and resubmitting until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. Every time you change some text in your custom stories, you need to delete and reimport all the translation strings from the "Locale > Translate open graph stories" menu. After reimporting I found some untralsated strings.